# Conflicts between 2 NICs

Tags: networking, windows-server-2003, network-adapter

I have an HP server (Windows Server 2003) with 2 external NICs (couldn't get the builtin NIC to work).

One is for an internal network of 4 PCs and the other is for part of an Internet-facing network.  Many times a day, we have to disable the internal NIC in order to get the other NIC to see the network.

I know this is happening on a server, but the issue is more related to the conflicts on the NICs.  Any suggestions from the community on where to look for a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Realised that Windows did not like to play with 2 NICs.  Workaround was to create a persistent static routes for the internal network with a "route -p add ...."

Comment: Hmmm.  I have multi-homed several Windows servers over the years and never had to do that.  Windows works just fine with multiple NICs.  Just remember that only the Internet facing one should have a gateway applied in this configuration.

Comment: You may well have a point about the Internet facing one having a gateway applied.  Point noted.
We also have 4 other Window servers multi-homed which did not have a problem, but the difference being that these four units connect to a Layer3 switch, whereas this particular unit only connects to a HP ProCurve switch.